# Minifier output JSP - Spring Boot

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, minify

I want to compress output from jsp file in my Spring Boot Application. I tried to compresses the original file jsp but I think it is not the solution.

Output of the page like that mkyong. Can anyone suggest me a method?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before asking help, you are expected to invest some of your own effort into the problem and provide the best of the solutions you've come up with (in code if possible) alongside with the solutions that you've tried and that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Compressor HTML taglib. I think you can read this tutorial, it's pretty good:

[JSP Taglib HTML Compressor And Minifier](https://w3stacks.com/spring-boot/jsp-taglib-html-compressor-and-minifier)

Comment: This article doesn't exist currently. Please put another link or explain better.